# Dynamically add MenuItems to a MenuItem and statically view them

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, menuitem

I want to dynamically add some `MenuItems` to a `MenuItem.ChildItems`, but I want to see them statically. In other words, I just want to let the `MenuItems` always be visible and not only when I hover over it.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < lista.count; i++)
{
    MenuItem nuovo = new MenuItem();

    nuovo.NavigateUrl = "www.google.com"
    nuovo.Text = "prova" + i;

    attualeItem.ChildItems.Add(nuovo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify 1 to 2 properties of your `Menu` control:

**StaticDisplayLevels**: 2 - *The number of levels displayed in the static part of the menu*.

- 2 if you have only Parents and Children. It will increase depending on how many levels deep is your menu.

**StaticSubMenuIndent** ***(Optional)***: *The indentation between a static menu item and its static sub-menu items*.

- So you will set this to 20px or 30px, or whatever distance you want them apart.